# How to send commands to an open application window?

Tags: c++, windows

I have a program that opens an application through PsExec remoting. When the application is opened, I can do one of two things:

1. Open the application in the same cmd window (changes the title of the window)

or

2. Open the application in its own window (also changes the title)

This application needs to run different commands at different points of my program based on different conditions. I want to know how to send commands through a C++ program into the new window.

Regular `system()` commands only work through `cmd` so that doesn't work. I've tried `CreateProcess()` which works in opening but I can't figure out how to send additional commands with it. I've read about pipes and that seems like it could be a solution but I don't know enough about them to know the answer.

Thanks

Comment: If you just want to pass some startup parameters you can use `CreateProcess` with the `lpCommandLine` parameter (or similarly with `system`). If you need more than that you need some IPC mechanism: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/ipc/interprocess-communications.

Comment: ```CreateProcess``` and ```system``` work fine initially but since a new application is opened, they don't work past startup for sending commands.

Comment: As I noted, in this case you should use an IPC mechanism (pipe, socket, shared-memory etc. - see the link above).

Comment: A pipe would require code on both sides (server and client), correct? If I don't have access to the source code for the application I'm running, is that no longer an option?

Comment: Any form of IPC (including pipes) will require code on both sides.